# How do I marble-test an observable of void values?

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, rxjs-marbles

Using RXJS's `TestScheduler`, is there a nice way to marble-test an event-like observable that emits `undefined` values?

I am using TypeScript, so type circumvention / monkey-patching is not desirable.

```js
testScheduler.schedule(() => valueEmittingWork(), 20);
testScheduler.schedule(() => valueEmittingWork(), 40);

testScheduler.run(rx => {
    rx.expectObservable(myObservable).toBe(`20ms ??? 19ms ???`);
    // Above uses the new time progression syntax. What do I put instead of ???
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I piped the source observable with `.mapTo('a')` and then was able to write:

```js
testScheduler.run(rx => {
    rx.expectObservable(myObservable.pipe(mapTo('a'))).toBe(`20ms a 19ms a`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test a void observable by setting `a` to `undefined`:

```js
testScheduler.run(rx => {
    rx.expectObservable(myObservable).toBe('20ms a 10ms a', { a: undefined });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`const source$ = hot<void>('a--')`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**